# Delete rows by content in HBase

Tags: java, nosql, hbase

What is the most simple/efficient way to delete all rows with **columns** NOT matching any pattern from a list (using Java API)?

Pseudocode to make it clear:

```
patterns = ["hbase", "rules"]
awesomeTable.delete {
    row, family =>
         ! patterns.exists(pattern => family.column.matches(pattern))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hbase, there is no direct and efficient way of selecting the row by content, 
Hbase is like a Map, you can only fetch rows by keys(range).

One possible way is using Filters, but it makes it very slow

Take a look at value filter

http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/ValueFilter.html